# Which RadonAway fan is this?

Tags: radon

I am replacing my RadonAway fan which has seemingly burnt out. However, the sticker on the current fan identifying the part number is self-contradictory:
[image: Which model number?]
It's marked as an RP265, but [part number 23032-1 is the RP260](https://www.homedepot.com/p/RadonAway-RP260-Radon-Fan-23032-1/203746905) while [23033-1 is the RP265](https://www.homedepot.com/p/RadonAway-RP265-Radon-Fan-23033-1/203746907). Since there is a difference in flow rate, I want to make sure I purchase the correct one -- which one should I buy?

Comment: Not a shopping question *per se* -- this is very specific and answerable, as well as being of persistent value (the question is the part number discrepancy, the OP already knows where to buy it and what generally to buy)

Comment: better source, same conflicting numbers. 
 https://www.radonaway.com/products/radon-fans/rp265.php  Do you see a watt/amp rating?

Comment: The only people likely to know are at the manufacturer.  If they are putting conflicting info on their products and web site, there's really no other source that would know better.

Comment: @fixer1234 good point. I'll call them tomorrow.

Comment: With something as serious as radon, go with the higher flow rate. I suspect your model is discontinued and the replacement is not exact but improved.   RP265c - 23033-1

Answer (score 2):

I spoke to the manufacturer this morning and they confirmed that a small number of units went out with the incorrect part number but with the correct model number. So this is the RP265.